# How do I remove the next token from the stream in LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3, expl3

I want to remove a token from the stream from within a command (ignoring spaces).  The next token will be a `{` (actually, I've just thought that it might not be ... but I'll continue as if it were).  In "ordinary" TeX I would end the command with `\let\junk=`.  LaTeX3 has lots of `\peek_<something>_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF` commands which would do it, except that there's an unnecessary conditional there which seems like overkill.

So what's the LaTeX3 equivalent of `let\junk=`?

Comment: I don't think there is; `\cs_new_protected:Npn \stacey_remove_token_ignore_spaces: { \peek_charcode_remove_ignore_spaces:NF \scan_stop: {} }`

Comment: IIRC, @egreg's suggestion will only remove the next token if it is a control sequence, no?  There is no `\let\junk=` in LaTeX3, because it is quite rare that you wish to unconditionally remove whatever tokens follow, I believe.  One option is always `\cs_set_eq:NN \junk`, but it is not very appealing.

Comment: Could you expand the context here? As Bruno says, this is quite a rare thing to need to do other than inside `\peek_...` type constructs.

Comment: @JosephWright The context is that I've just done an "If next char is X" test.  I don't want to remove the token at that stage because if it *isn't* X then I need to keep it where it is.  But if it is X then I want to ignore it and move on to the next token.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds very much like you are after the 'peek and remove if true' functions, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo
  {
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF a
      { Nope,~an~`a' \par }
      { It's~OK~ma,~it's~only~ } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\demo ab

\demo c
\end{document}
```